# Compute $N! \ \mathrm{mod}P$ , where $N<=10^9$ and $P=10^9+7$, where $N!$ is $N$ factorial

Tags: factorial, fast-fourier-transform

I have seen several web pages which mention that this task can be done efficiently using FFT. But, I didn't find any reliable source which can help me understand the process underneath.
It will be great in case someone can help in the computation of factorial of $N$ modulo $(10^9+7)$.

Comment: $10^9+7$???? Are you sure this is not from Project Euler, Spoj, or some such contest? They often use moduli like that. And don't approve of contestants asking for outside help.

Comment: Yes this is from Spoj. 
http://www.spoj.com/problems/FACTMODP/ 
This question has tag of FFT. Therefore, I asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can find N! in sqrt(n) * polylog(n) using FFT.
Read More : http://fredrikj.net/blog/2012/03/factorials-mod-n-and-wilsons-theorem/

This can even be used to find nCr for large n and r by using modulo inverse using Fermat's Little Thm / extended euclid.